Legality of Housing-Based Loans Based on Race
Is it legal for an institution to refuse to extend a loan for a home to someone based on their race? Perhaps it depends on the institution (those receiving federal funds, banks, nonprofits, etc.)
What laws or constitutional arguments prevent it?
For example, a Vermont nonprofit gave home equity loans with racial criteria. source

If the lender is not a governmental entity, no constitutional arguments apply.

@ohwilleke But anti-discrimination laws apply, don't they?

@Barmar They might. My comment was only a quick hit to the easy part of any answer without looking into the hard part.

I'm confused why this is downvoted. This is a pretty clear, specific question within the jurisdiction of the United States.

From Equal Credit Opportunity Act (emphasis mine):

The [ECOA], 15 U.S.C. 1691 et seq. prohibits creditors from discriminating against credit applicants on the basis of race, color, religion, national origin, sex, marital status, age, because an applicant receives income from a public assistance program, or because an applicant has in good faith exercised any right under the Consumer Credit Protection Act.

While I think this is normally interpreted as prohibiting discrimination against marginalized groups, it should also apply to restricting loans only to marginalized groups. The program mentioned in the question only loans to black, indigenous, and people of color, so I think it may violate this law.
This program might get around this law by claiming to be a grantor rather than a creditor. They provide the home buyer with a zero-interest loan, but if the buyer stays in the home for 3 years they don't have to repay the loan.

It sounds like this is a grant and not a loan, therefore the organization isn't a creditor.

The website says "Our HEP Down Payment Assistance product provides a bridge to homeownership with 0.00% interest loans ..."

Although it turns into a grant if they live in the home for 3 years, because they don't have to repay the loan.

Keep reading. "To be eligible, the buyer: must purchase a CHT shared equity home". CHT buys a share of the house, then grants it after 3 years. This avoids them loaning money.

OK, I'm not really sure how this shared equity ownership works. I tried looking it up in Investopedia, but I don't know how it applies to this case.

@user71659 Unless they offer the no-interest loan to everyone, and only restrict the forgiveness part to BIPOC, it still seems like there's a credit restriction.
